# NodeJS: how to create a flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I am struggling how to create a flag in nodejs. Please refer to small code below to get my idea

```
var isLogged = "no"

function login(){
    this.isLogged = "yes"
}

function sendText(){
    if(this.isLogged == "yes"){
      console.log("Hello World")
    }
}
```

In nodeJS, variable seems not to support this. Please advice me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Did you see some sort of error? What was it? Did something not work as you expected? What happened, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: create a parent object

Comment: What is `this` referring to here? (That depends on how these functions are called.) Perhaps `var isLogged = "no"` should be `this.isLogged = "no"` in a constructor, or perhaps `this.isLogged` should just be `isLogged` elsewhere. There's really not enough information here to help you.

Comment: you'd need to persist the data in sessions for such flags. if you are using express, use express-session along backed by redis or mongodb to store session data.

Comment: Sorry, if I made you guys confused, I am so new with node js, so sometimes I don't really know the issue, just try to explain my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no windows object in node use variable indexing. like this.

```js
var isLogged = 'no'

function login() {
  isLogged = "yes"
}

function sendText() {
  if (isLogged == "yes") {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }
}

console.log(isLogged);
login()
sendText();
console.log(isLogged);
```

Comment: Hi Arrow, without the "this", the variable is not updated. It's always "no"

Comment: @PeterPham then the example you've given does not satisfy the "complete" requirement of [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just try to go simple, and forget the `this` scope. Just reassign.

```js
var isLogged = "no";

function login(){
    isLogged = "yes";
}

function sendText(){
    if(isLogged == "yes"){
      console.log("Hello World");
    }
}
```